# Set Limit Title Product Opencart

Tags: php, opencart-3

I try to limit the length of a title product name to 20 characters in the category page.
I tried to change

```
'name' => $ result ['name'], to
'name' => substr ($ result ['name'], 0.20). '& hellip;',
```

in  / controller / product / category.php
as I found over internet, but it didn't work.
I use Opnecart3 with Journal3 theme.
Can someone help me?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

To correctly `substr` in OC you should use this syntax.

```
'name' => utf8_substr(trim(strip_tags(html_entity_decode($result['name'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))), 0, 20) . '...',
```

Comment: I tried your solution does not work and I do not understand why. I use use op3 theme Journal3.

Answer (score 0):

your substr function syntax is wrong

```
'name'=>substr($result['name'],0,20)
```

Comment: I also tried this option.
I think maybe I don't edit where I should.